# ASP.NET : How to do IIS Indexing search feature for my website

Tags: asp.net, search

I want to implement a search feature to my webapplication which has 50 + static files which are rich in meta tag contents. I want to add one ASP.NET page to the application which would show the searchresults when someone go for a search. Can anyone guide me how to go ahead ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at an article - https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5032858.html

> SUMMARY: How the Indexing Service
>   provides a powerful search feature for
>   LANs and Internet users.

[Indexing with Internet Information Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692947(VS.85).aspx)

> SUMMARY: Indexing Service provides
>   search capabilities to Web sites
>   hosted with Internet Information
>   Services (IIS). With Indexing Service,
>   you can provide searchable access to
>   both intranet and Internet Web sites.
>   You can index remote computers and
>   multiple Web servers.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Lucene.net. Plenty of examples are out there.